# how can I second time show my view controller without calling viewdidload?

Tags: ios, swift

here is my scenario case.
  [image]
Initially **for going to this VC without loading** is hidden.when I click to first view controllers button it goes to second view controller.When I click button from secondVC it come back to first one and **for going to this VC without loading** button is now visible.Now when I click **for going to this VC without loading** I want to show my second view controller without **reload** because my previous loaded data for second view controller is needed.So how can I do that?

the actual scenario of my app look like this.My first VC

[image]

and the second one.

[image]

It's a picture of sound cloud but the case is same.

Comment: There are different solution for this problem,:
(a) You can store your data in persistently, and with the help of property you  can manage if u need to load the data from server side or from storage.
(b) you can add the your viewcontroller's view onto the your first view controller as subview.

Comment: Why don't you try to send the data that you have to the second VC? There is no matter will it be reloaded or not, you can make any behaviour sending the data. I can send only one bool there, like "shouldReloadData: Bool", and then check it in the second VC

Comment: in this scenario, i think you can used NotificationCenter.

Comment: Both answers can work, but I consider this poor design. Let the OS deal with handling the view controller life cycles properly. In the comments, Woof has a good question - why does your design conflict with simply passing the data a second time? There are several ways to *not* hit up the back end - if you have one - a second time. @ZaidPathan's first solution, once you consider it, is reasonable but the views and their life cycles remain "owned" by the OS. His second solution, like the other answer, *also* keeps the OS using the view controller life cycles as designed.

Answer (score 1):

**First possible solution**,

Add **SecondViewController** as child view controller of **FirstViewController** using container view in Storyboard.

Every time you want to remove **SecondViewController** just **hide/remove** it with custom animation block.

Keep the reference of **SecondViewController** in **FirstViewController**

**Second possible solution**,

Create shared data object.

Then you can use that shared data object in any view controller, regardless of saving the state of any view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an **object** where i put the data und pass this from **ViewController** to **ViewController** by **properties**. Maybe this is to simple but it should work.